# Search Outlook attachments limited to a weekday before and save attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I want search though Outlook folders of now to previous weekday, so will exclude weekends, and if file doesn’t exist, output “this report was not sent on *date*”.

And for file to save as: following a condition that the title of the heading contains some text at most two. And that the file will be saved with the two found letters in the body of the title.

I want to do this for six different cases.

```
Sub SaveOutlookAttachments()
Dim ol As Outlook.Application 
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace  
Dim ofolder As Outlook.folder
Dim i As Object
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
Dim at As Outlook.Attachment

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set ofolder = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Inbox") 

For Each i In ofolder.Items

    If i.Class = olMail Then

        Set mi = i                  'This ensure that were looking at an email object rather than any potential item

        'I need to find a way to create a case or an if statement that would reference 2 keywords in the title of the email subject in order to download and save the file with those keywords + date at the end.
        'The logic is to use the title to distinguish between 4 regional reports for 1 Partner and 3 reports for 3 different partners. These would save files in their names associated with the title of the email. Eg: Comp.ABC Regional Reports 20/10/2019. I should also only search for previous days only within weekdays/working days - Mondays to Fridays.


        Debug.Print mi.SenderName, mi.ReceivedTime, mi.Attachments.Count

        For Each at In mi.Attachments

        at.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & at.FileName & Format(mi.ReceivedTime, "dd-mm-yyyy")   'Put in a valid folder location to store attachements

        Next at

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide your current code so we can see how far along you are and can better help out.

Comment: Are you trying to search for any attachment? A particular attachment file name? Or some string inside the attachment?

Comment: I think you need to break this down into smaller issues, I tackled something recently to download attachments from a specific sender, could be a place to start --> https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Microsoft+Outlook+-+VBA

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville, Please find code attached. Is there any help you can provide? The last comment made with the link helps but not with my specific ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code that first checks the MailItem's ReceivedTime for the Date condition (you can go further and exclude weekends). Then it checks the MailItem's Subject for Keywords from a `colKeywords` collection you can edit and add to. It also This should get you pretty close to what you want to do. I've also renamed the variables for clarity:

```
Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim colKeywords As New Collection
Dim sKeyword As String
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim iBackdate As Integer

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.Folders(1).Folders("Inbox")

' Add your Keywords here
colKeywords.Add "keyword1"
colKeywords.Add "keyword2"

For Each objItem In objFolder.Items

    ' Check Item Class
    If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

        ' Set as Mail Item
        Set objMailItem = objItem

        With objMailItem

            Select Case Weekday(Now)
                Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                    iBackdate = 3
                Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                    iBackdate = 4
                Case Else ' Other days
                    iBackdate = 2
            End Select

            ' Check date
            If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then

                ' Loop through all keywords
                For iCounter = 1 To colKeywords.Count

                    ' Get keyword
                    sKeyword = colKeywords.Item(iCounter)

                    ' Check if keyword exists
                    If InStr(.Subject, sKeyword) > 0 Then

                        ' Save Attachments
                        For Each objAttachment In .Attachments

                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & objAttachment.FileName & Format(.ReceivedTime, "dd-mm-yyyy")   'Put in a valid folder location to store attachements

                        Next

                    End If

                Next

            End If

        End With

    End If

Next
```

Comment: 1st of all, many thanks to the code above. Just one small ask please as I'm super new to VBA: Struggling to locate how to format date so for Monday, it pulls data from Friday. Can you help with that, please?

Comment: Added extra logic for days of the week, you can adjust if necessary. Please mark the answer as accepted when you get a chance using the gray checkbox next to the answer.